# I can’t use HLSL intrinsic functions for DXR like : TraceRay() , ReportHit() and …

Tags: 3d, hlsl, directx-12

The compiler provides this error message : Function ‘TraceRay(RaytracingAccelerationStructure, int, int, int, int, int, RayDesc, HitInfo)’ is not declared.

Pease help me. I have searched a lot and it seems like no else has had such a problem!

Comment: Are you using a Shader Model 6.3 or later profile with the ``DXC.EXE`` compiler? Are you using a ``lib_*`` profile? Please provide a code snippet and the compilation build settings you are using.